# Can you connect an NVMe M.2 to a SATA port?

Tags: sata, pci-express, nvme

There are some questions similar to this, but they usually point to specific hardware, and do not have a technical answer.

Around the web there are several M.2-to-SATA adapters, but most of them (if not all) do not support NVMe (only old M.2 drives).  But, at the same time, I found some external M.2-to-USB cases that apparently support NVMe (at least, the resellers say they do).

Generically speaking, is it possible to connect an NVMe M.2 to a standard SATA port? (of course, with the aid of an adapter and some loss of speed)  If so, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is: Yes, you can do it. You will of course lose speed. If you were asking about USB, I'd say go for usb-c or thunderbolt if you have it since you can get insane speeds from an external NVMe drive that way. I think SATA might be even slower than that but yes, you can do it with an adapter.

Comment: Indeed, all M.2-to-USB adapters I found that support NVMe were type C.